# Python Scrapy - scraping dt and dd values

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to obtain all data inside dt/dd table structure on a website.

My current code looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class KonzumTestSingleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "konzum_test_single"
    start_urls = ["https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik"]

    def parse(self, response):
        dt_list = response.xpath("//*[@id='content-start']//section//dl/dt")

        for dt in dt_list:
            productTable = {}
            
            productTable["Opisna_tablica"] = dt.xpath("./text()").extract_first(default="").strip()
            productTable["ddValue"] = dt.xpath("./following-sibling::dd/text()").extract_first(default="").strip()

            yield productTable
```

This is the result, somewhat "correct, but not desired output". My desired output would be data below but returned in one request and for some reason Scrapy is returning data in multiple requests, if I am reading debug data correctly.

```
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik> (referer: None)
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Naziv proizvoda', 'ddValue': 'Miješano mljeveno meso. Mljeveno meso.'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Neto količina', 'ddValue': '850 g'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Sastojci / Sastav:', 'ddValue': 'juneće meso 50%, svinjsko meso 49%, sol. Postotak masti manji od 30%. Omjer kolagena i bjelančevina mesa manji od 18%.'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Dodatne informacije', 'ddValue': 'Pakirano u kontroliranoj atmosferi.'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Upute za upotrebu/pripremu', 'ddValue': 'Proizvod termički obraditi prije konzumacije.'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Uvjeti čuvanja', 'ddValue': 'Čuvati na temperaturi do +2 C.'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Zemlja podrijetla (mjesto podrijetla)', 'ddValue': 'Zemlja rođenja: EU, Zemlja uzgoja: Hrvatska, Zaklano u: Hrvatska HR10EU, Zemlja rasijecanja: Hrvatska HR10EU
, Proizvedeno u: R.Hrvatska.'}
2020-08-09 23:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'Opisna_tablica': 'Odgovorna osoba / Stavlja ne tržište:', 'ddValue': 'PIK Vrbovec plus d.o.o., Zagrebačka 148, 10340 Vrbovec, Hrvatska.'}
```

This is how the website looks like:

```
<section data-toggle-section="animate" class="">
    <div data-toggle-trigger="" class="">
      <h3 class="b-bottom-space-gray-light fs-echo-gamma color-space-gray-dark py-05 f-weight-bold">
        Opis proizvoda
      </h3>

        <dl class="">
            <dt class="xh-highlight">Naziv proizvoda</dt>
            <dd class="">Miješano mljeveno meso. Mljeveno meso.</dd>
            <dt class="xh-highlight">Neto količina</dt>
            <dd class="">850 g</dd>
        </dl>
        </div>

        <div data-toggle-target="" style="display: none;" class="">
          <dl class="">
              <dt class="xh-highlight">Sastojci / Sastav:</dt>
              <dd class="">juneće meso 50%, svinjsko meso 49%, sol. Postotak masti manji od 30%. Omjer kolagena i bjelančevina mesa manji od 18%.</dd>
              <dt class="xh-highlight">Dodatne informacije</dt>
              <dd class="">Pakirano u kontroliranoj atmosferi.</dd>
              <dt class="xh-highlight">Upute za upotrebu/pripremu </dt>
              <dd class="">Proizvod termički obraditi prije konzumacije.</dd>
              <dt class="xh-highlight">Uvjeti čuvanja </dt>
              <dd class="">Čuvati na temperaturi do +2 C.</dd>
              <dt class="xh-highlight">Zemlja podrijetla (mjesto podrijetla)</dt>
              <dd class="">Zemlja rođenja: EU, Zemlja uzgoja: Hrvatska, Zaklano u: Hrvatska HR10EU, Zemlja rasijecanja: Hrvatska HR10EU, Proizvedeno u: R.Hrvatska.</dd>
              <dt class="xh-highlight">Odgovorna osoba / Stavlja ne tržište:</dt>
              <dd class="">PIK Vrbovec plus d.o.o., Zagrebačka 148, 10340 Vrbovec, Hrvatska.</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>

        <button data-toggle-trigger="" type="button" class="t-center fs-base w-100 p-1">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </button>

      </section>
```

**EDIT:** When I removed one indentation level from yield, I got this:

```
2020-08-10 00:13:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.konzum.hr/web/products/mijesano-mljeveno-meso-pakirano-850-g-pik>
{'dtValue': 'Odgovorna osoba / Stavlja ne tržište:', 'ddValue': 'PIK Vrbovec plus d.o.o., Zagrebačka 148, 10340 Vrbovec, Hrvatska.'}
```

Now, I am getting back only one result.

Comment: There is only 1 request. What you see in the logs is that there are multiple items returned  from this single request. If you want to return only a single item you can just fill up the productTable dictionary (and make you have a unique key per record of course) and remove one indentation from the yield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using a loop when you can grab all values directly ? Also you can shorten your XPath a lot :

```
dt = response.xpath('//dt/text()').getall()
dd = response.xpath('//dd/text()').getall()

data = dict(zip(dt, dd))
```

Comment: Yeah, solved my problem with your solution. First I extracted values into temporary table (dt and dd values) and after that I simply zipped them into dictionary. Thank you. The only thing I am afraid of is one tuple has more items than other tuple. In that case I will have n tuples less, but considering it is a very structured website, let's say this solution is more than welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you want but this will return a single item with ALL fields:

```
productTable = {}        
for dt in dt_list:        
    field = dt.xpath("./text()").extract_first(default="").strip()
    value = dt.xpath("./following-sibling::dd/text()").extract_first(default="").strip()
    productTable[field] = value 

yield productTable
```